# Creating a MSTest Unit Test on a method that calls on Membership - ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, mocking, mstest

I have an ASP.NET application framework 4, I am trying to test a Method in which at some point it calls :

```
var userKey = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```

Of course because no one is connected i get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." which is normal...

Does anyone have a way to work around this problem? Should I try to Mock the Membership (but being sealed this is touchy) or should I try to replace the service?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: This is not an MVC application

Comment: 2 ways. One is to wrap membership in factory class which can pass back a dummy object for testing. The other is to outright MOK membership.

Comment: do you have mstest? Mock is free framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i found the answer, I endup using something like this:

```
        Mock<IStaticMembershipService> membershipMock = new Mock<IStaticMembershipService>();
        Mock<MembershipUser> userMock = new Mock<MembershipUser>();

        userMock.Setup(u => u.ProviderUserKey).Returns(guid);
        membershipMock.Setup(s => s.GetUser()).Returns(userMock.Object);
```

The Class:

```
public interface IStaticMembershipService
{
    MembershipUser GetUser();

    void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user);
}

public class StaticMembershipService : IStaticMembershipService
{
    public System.Web.Security.MembershipUser GetUser()
    {
        return Membership.GetUser();
    }

    public void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user)
    {
        Membership.UpdateUser(user);
    }
}
```